# Pause a countdowntimer from another method within the same class

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to pause a countdown timer using the .cancel() function. But it won't pause.

My cdTimer is a global variable in order for me to access in from another method.

```
public void startTimer()
{
    //create timer
    cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLimit, 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             timeLeft = (int)millisUntilFinished;
             if(millisUntilFinished < 60000)
                 timer.setText("Time : 00 : " + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) );
             else if(millisUntilFinished >= 60000 && millisUntilFinished < 120000)
                 timer.setText("Time : 01 : " + String.valueOf((millisUntilFinished / 2) / 1000));
             else if(millisUntilFinished >= 120000 && millisUntilFinished < 180000)
                 timer.setText("Time : 02 : " + String.valueOf((millisUntilFinished / 3) / 1000));

             if(millisUntilFinished < 20000)
                 timer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
         }
         public void onFinish() {
             showGameOverScreen();
         }
         }.start();
}
```

Then from another method, I'm trying to access it just like this.

```
public void pauseMenu() 
{
     cdTimer.cancel();
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: where did you declare the "cdTimer". Is it global? What is the issue you are facing? Please be more specific.

Comment: I stated it at my post, "My cdTimer is a global variable" Please ready properly before answering/commenting. It is also stated there that my cdTimer won't pause.